# PHP: Calculate with cents

Tags: php, currency

I got the following problem: I got values like

```
2,50
1
2,99
```

Now I would like to separate them into 2 parts like this:

```
2 and 50
1 and 00
2 and 99


 $euro      =   explode('.', $item->price)[0]; 

 if(array_key_exists(1, explode('.', $item->price))) { 
    $cent   =   explode('.', $item->price)[1]; 
 }
 else
 { 
    $cent   =   "00"; 
 }
```

That's ***not*** the way I should do that I guess ;-)

There is another problem: Now I get the following values:

```
2 and 5
1 and 00
2 and 99
```

But it should be

```
2 and 50
1 and 00
2 and 99
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? to get 50, and not 5, you need to use strval() , so that it is cast as string, will number_format() work for you? or money_format() ?

Comment: to add that 0 to make 50 you can use `str_pad($cent,2,0)`

Comment: I need to do that because the webdesigner adds a special class to cent-values ;-)

Comment: Do you get float values or strings as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, a decently short way of doing it:

```
$x = '2.55';

$a = explode('.',$x);

$euro = $a[0];
$cent = count($a) >= 2 ? $a[1] : '00';
```

Output:

```
2 and 55
```

Keep in mind that you cannot have two dots in your string at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$value = 2.50;
$big = ($value%10);
$small = ($value-$big)*100;
echo "Value: ".$value."\n";
echo "Big: ".$big."\n";
echo "Small: ".$small."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have floats (or strings with a dot as decimal separator) as input:

```php
$euro = (string)floor($input);
$cent = str_pad(($input - $euro) * 100, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

In case you get strings with a comma as separator, prepend:

```php
$input = str_replace(",", ".", $input);
```